# Pause video on slide

Tags: html, html5-video, angular9, swiper.js

I want to pause the **VIDEO** when I slide by dragging or using slide next, prev buttons.
It doesn't matter which slider. it can be useful-swiper or owl-carousel

I'm using ngx-useful-swiper as my Carousel.
I can use ngx-owl-carousel-o instead, But if it worked with anyone
**My HTML**

```
<swiper [config]="heroSlider" #usefulSwiper>
              <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide text-center" *ngFor="let item of sections.about_video; index as i">
                  <video
                    poster="{{ fileUrl + item.thumbnail }}"
                    playsinline
                    autoplay="false"
                    muted
                    controls="false"
                    onloadedmetadata="this.muted = true"
                    src="{{ fileUrl + item.video }}"
                    id="video"
                    #video
                  ></video>
                </div>
              </div>
              <button class="btn p-0 btn-prev" (click)="previousSlide()">
                <svg
                  version="1.1"
                  id="Layer_1"
                  x="0px"
                  y="0px"
                  viewBox="0 0 26 43"
                  style="enable-background: new 0 0 26 43"
                  xml:space="preserve"
                >
                  <path
                    id="Path_3540"
                    class="st0"
                    d="M21.5,43c2.5,0,4.5-2,4.5-4.5c0-1.2-0.5-2.4-1.3-3.2L10.9,21.5L24.7,7.7
                                                    c1.7-1.8,1.7-4.7-0.1-6.4c-1.8-1.7-4.5-1.7-6.3,0l-16.9,17c-1.8,1.8-1.8,4.6,0,6.4l16.9,17C19.1,42.5,20.3,43,21.5,43z"
                  />
                </svg>
              </button>
              <button class="btn p-0 btn-next" (click)="nextSlide()">
                <svg
                  class="icon"
                  version="1.1"
                  id="Layer_1"
                  x="0px"
                  y="0px"
                  viewBox="0 0 26 43"
                  style="enable-background: new 0 0 26 43"
                  xml:space="preserve"
                >
                  <path
                    id="Path_3539"
                    class="st0"
                    d="M4.5,43C2,43,0,41,0,38.5c0-1.2,0.5-2.4,1.3-3.2l13.7-13.8L1.3,7.7c-1.7-1.8-1.7-4.7,0.1-6.4c1.8-1.7,4.5-1.7,6.3,0l16.9,17c1.8,1.8,1.8,4.6,0,6.4l-16.9,17C6.9,42.5,5.7,43,4.5,43z"
                  />
                </svg>
              </button>
</swiper>
```

**My TS**

```
heroSlider: SwiperOptions = {
    loop: false,
    slidesPerView: 1,
    on: {
      transitionEnd: function (Swiper) {
        console.log(Swiper);
      },
    },
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply mean you want to pause video when you click the next or previous buttons, you can add a listener for those buttons and in that listener pause the video.

Some example below showing adding an ID to the button and then using this to find the button in your Javascript and add a listener.

You can add a resume button also or just have the user click play on the video.

```html
 <button id="btnNext" class="btn p-0 btn-prev" (click)="previousSlide()">
```

```js
var vid1 = document.getElementById("YourVideoID");
var btnNext = document.getElementById("NextButton");
var btnPrev = document.getElementById("PrevButton");
var btnResume = document.getElementById("PrevButton");

btnNext.addEventListener("click", function() {
     vid1.pause()
});

btnPrev.addEventListener("click", function() {
     vid1.pause()
});

btnResume.addEventListener("click", function() {
     vid1.play()
});
```